# Does error handling on every query affects performance?

Tags: php, sql

Hello i'm wondering if putting error handler in every query especially Inserts and Updates affects the performance of web application with huge database? if not how can i use try catch properly on every query to stop the process and inform the user? is it possible to rollback inserted data?

sample error logging:

```
     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into `table`(`fields`) values('$variable')");

     if(!$query){
         write_mysql_log("logs here", $conn);
         echo "<script>alert('Error message, like something went wrong'); window.location = 'page.php';</script>";
     }
```

Comment: Error handling does not affect performance. It is a very good practice to always check for errors when running sql queries in your application, and that's what error handlers are here for.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You should be checking for errors from the query.

The check for errors is entirely separate from running the query itself.  The query will still return errors, even if you don't check for them.